# Extracting information from web through Excel or VBA

Tags: html, excel, vba, web-scraping

I am a beginner of coding. I am now learning how to get information from web through Excel or VBA.

My question can be ask through below example:
In below link (https://www.schooland.hk/ss/tsuen-wan),
when you click those individual blue wordings in the red circle which I shown, it will leads to individual pages.
[image]
In all those individual pages, for example (https://www.schooland.hk/ss/twgss), they also have a part like this showing same kind of information, like phone number etc.(As circled below). 
[image]

My work is to use a spreadsheet, like excel, show a table which listed all those individual wordings' informations in the red circled without using copy and paste.

How could I do it?

Comment: google for VBA webscraping. Or go there, for example https://www.wiseowl.co.uk/blog/s393/scrape-website-html.htm

Answer (score 0):

The following using XHR to achieve your task.

---

**Notes:**

---

`GetSchoolInfo` is the main sub.

It sends the initial request to `"https://www.schooland.hk/ss/tsuen-wan"` .It uses the function `GetHTMLDoc` to return an HTML document for the webpage URL passed in.

The links to individual schools you show in the first red circled area can be retrieved using a CSS selector of

```
.school-table a
```

["." means className](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_class.asp), so `.school-table` means all elements with className `school-table`.
 [" a" means all a tags contained within](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_element_element.asp) that.

---

Sample results returned by this CSS query:

[image: CSS query]

---

The actual HTML returned for each link is like the following:

```
<A title="Tsuen Wan Government Secondary School" href="about:twgss">??????</A>
```

We can make use of the fact that each linked to page uses the short string after `about:` i.e. `twggs` concatentated with a general base string of `"https://www.schooland.hk/ss/"`, to give each school specific URL i.e. 
 `"https://www.schooland.hk/ss/twggs"`.

Function `GethRefSubString` obtains this short string which is concantenated with the general base string  `BASEURL`. This school specific link is the added to the `schoolLinks` collection.

---

The `schoolLinks` collection is looped using `GetHTMLDoc` to process the links into school specific new HTML documents.

---

The contact info on each school page, the second red circled area in your question, resides with an `HTMLDivElement` with className `contact`. The appropriate index is 0 i.e. the first matching className in the collection (also the only!).

[image: Contact class]

All the required contact info can be accessed via the `.innerText` property of the `HTMLDivElement`.

---

**Example webpage content:**

[image: webpage]

---

**Example code output:**

[image: Code output]

---

**VBA Code:**

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub GetSchoolInfo()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim xmlHttp As Object, html As HTMLDocument, links As Object
    Const BASEURL As String = "https://www.schooland.hk/ss/"
    Set xmlHttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.6.0")
    Set html = GetHTMLDoc("https://www.schooland.hk/ss/tsuen-wan", xmlHttp)
    Set links = html.querySelectorAll(".school-table a[href]") 'get all

    Dim link As Long, schoolLinks As Collection
    Set schoolLinks = New Collection
    For link = 0 To links.Length - 1
        schoolLinks.Add BASEURL & GethRefSubString(links(link).outerHTML)
    Next link

    Dim currentLink, counter As Long
    With ActiveSheet
        For Each currentLink In schoolLinks
            counter = counter + 1
            Set html = GetHTMLDoc(currentLink, xmlHttp)
            Dim contactInfo As Object            '<HTMLDivElement
            Set contactInfo = html.getElementsByClassName("contact")(0)
            .Cells(counter, 1) = contactInfo.innerText
        Next currentLink
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Public Function GetHTMLDoc(ByVal url As String, ByRef xmlHttp As Object) As HTMLDocument
    With xmlHttp
        .Open "GET", url, False
        .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml"
        .send
        Dim html As HTMLDocument
        Set html = New HTMLDocument
        html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With
    Set GetHTMLDoc = html
End Function

Public Function GethRefSubString(ByVal aString As String) As String
    GethRefSubString = Split(Split(aString, "href=""about:")(1), Chr$(34))(0)
End Function
```

---

**References required:**

1. VBE > Tools > References > HTML Object library